# TopoJSON: how to calculate scale and translate?

Tags: python, topojson

### Context:

I'm using the [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) file format along with d3. Since I could not find a library in Python that handles this format, I'm writing one. I've got the topojson to other formats working.

### Question:

**When converting other formats to topojson, how do I calculate the ideal value for the topojson transforms `scale` and `translate`?**

In order to save space (among other tricks), the format uses relative integer offsets from the previous point. For example, this is the topojson file for Aruba:

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "transform": {
    "scale": [0.036003600360036005, 0.017361589674592462],
    "translate": [-180, -89.99892578124998]
  },
  "objects": {
    "aruba": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "arcs": [[0]],
      "id": 533
    }
  },
  "arcs": [
    [[3058, 5901], [0, -2], [-2, 1], [-1, 3], [-2, 3], [0, 3], [1, 1], 
     [1, -3], [2, -5], [1, -1]]
  ]
}
```

The same information as a GeoJSON feature looks like this:

```
{
    "type" : "Feature",
    "id" : 533,
    "properties" : {},
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [[
                 [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133], 
                 [-69.9009900990099, 12.417091709170947], 
                 [-69.97299729972997, 12.43445329884554], 
                 [-70.00900090009, 12.486538067869319], 
                 [-70.08100810081008, 12.538622836893097], 
                 [-70.08100810081008, 12.590707605916876], 
                 [-70.04500450045005, 12.608069195591469], 
                 [-70.00900090009, 12.55598442656769], 
                 [-69.93699369936994, 12.469176478194726], 
                 [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133]
            ]]
    }
}
```

It is easy to see how the former is more compact than the later. In order to obtain the absolute coordinates, the function is:

```
def arc_to_coordinates(topology, arc):
    scale = topology['transform']['scale']
    translate = topology['transform']['translate']

    x = 0
    y = 0
    coordinates = []

    for point in arc:
        x += point[0]
        y += point[1]
        coordinates.append([
            x * scale[0] + translate[0],
            y * scale[1] + translate[1] 
        ])

    return coordinates
```

Reading topojson is easy enough:

```
>>> arc_to_coordinates(topology, topology['arcs'][0])
[[-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133],
 [-69.9009900990099, 12.417091709170947],
 [-69.97299729972997, 12.43445329884554],
 [-70.00900090009, 12.486538067869319],
 [-70.08100810081008, 12.538622836893097],
 [-70.08100810081008, 12.590707605916876],
 [-70.04500450045005, 12.608069195591469],
 [-70.00900090009, 12.55598442656769],
 [-69.93699369936994, 12.469176478194726],
 [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133]]
```

### Update:

Reading Mike Bostock's code, I saw this:

```
kx = ((Q - 1) / (x1 - x0)) if x1 - x0 else 1
ky = ((Q - 1) / (y1 - y0)) if y1 - y0 else 1
...
scale = [1/kx, 1/ky]
```

In the example, given the bounding box in the form (x0, y0, x1, y1), Q seems to be around 6 and 12 for the values [0.036003600360036005, 0.017361589674592462].

```
>>> x0, y0, x1, y1
(-70.08100810081008, 12.417091709170947, -69.9009900990099, 12.608069195591469)
>>> Q = 6
>>> 1 / ((Q - 1) / (x1 - x0))
0.036003600360035644
>>> Q = 12
>>> 1/ ((Q - 1) / (y1 - y0))
0.017361589674592892
```

I know the Q has to do with quantization, any idea where the Q values near 6 and 12 came from?

Answer (score 4):

In Python

> "Functions that extract GeoJSON-ish data structures from TopoJSON
>   (https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) topology data.
>
> Author: Sean Gillies (https://github.com/sgillies)"

Example:

```
from itertools import chain

def rel2abs(arc, scale=None, translate=None):
    """Yields absolute coordinate tuples from a delta-encoded arc.

    If either the scale or translate parameter evaluate to False, yield the
    arc coordinates with no transformation."""
    if scale and translate:
        a, b = 0, 0
        for ax, bx in arc:
            a += ax
            b += bx
            yield scale[0]*a + translate[0], scale[1]*b + translate[1]
    else:
        for x, y in arc:
            yield x, y
```

https://github.com/sgillies/topojson/blob/master/topojson.py

Comment: I got this leg working already (the `arc_to_coordinates`), what I want is the `abs2rel(...)`. Note that `abs2rel` is trivial if you know the values of `scale` and `translate`, I want to know the algorithm for getting these from a list of absolute coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I ported the TopoJSON code from JavaScript to Python, following the exact same format Mike uses in his library (along with his +300 tests).

It is called `pytopojson` and supports conversion from GeoJSON to TopoJSON and vice versa. To do the conversion, just run:

```py
from pytopojson import feature

topojson = {
  "type": "Topology",
  "transform": {
    "scale": [0.036003600360036005, 0.017361589674592462],
    "translate": [-180, -89.99892578124998]
  },
  "objects": {
    "aruba": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "arcs": [[0]],
      "id": 533
    }
  },
  "arcs": [
    [[3058, 5901], [0, -2], [-2, 1], [-1, 3], [-2, 3], [0, 3], [1, 1], 
     [1, -3], [2, -5], [1, -1]]
  ]
}

feature_ = feature.Feature()

aruba = feature_(topojson, "aruba")
```

If you print this, you will get your GeoJSON object:

```py
{
   "id":533,
   "type":"Feature",
   "properties":{

   },
   "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
         [
            [
               -69.9009900990099,
               12.451814888520133
            ],
            [
               -69.9009900990099,
               12.417091709170947
            ],
            [
               -69.97299729972997,
               12.43445329884554
            ],
            [
               -70.00900090009,
               12.486538067869319
            ],
            [
               -70.08100810081008,
               12.538622836893097
            ],
            [
               -70.08100810081008,
               12.590707605916876
            ],
            [
               -70.04500450045005,
               12.608069195591469
            ],
            [
               -70.00900090009,
               12.55598442656769
            ],
            [
               -69.93699369936994,
               12.469176478194726
            ],
            [
               -69.9009900990099,
               12.451814888520133
            ]
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

You can also use the command-line tool located in the `bin` folder:

```bsh
python topo2geo.py aruba=- < aruba_topojson_file
```

To install it, you just have to run:

```bsh
pip install pytopojson
```

Let me know if this was helpful to you!

Answer (score -1):

Calvin Metcalf has a Python translation. He started a [draft spec](https://gist.github.com/calvinmetcalf/6301636).